# Correct way of reading from stdin in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a program that depending on the arguments given works in different ways:

- If there are 2 arguments - it takes 2nd argument as a filename, reads from it and then simply prints it out.
- If there is 1 argument - it reads from stdin and also prints it out.

Here is the code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do

-- Read given arguments
args <- getArgs

-- If file containing gramma was given
if length args == 2 then do
    hfile <- openFile (last args) ReadMode
    content <- hGetContents hfile
    let inGramma = getGramma content
    doJob (head args) inGramma
    hClose hfile
    return ()

-- If no file was given - reads from stdin
else if length args == 1 then do
    content <- getContents
    let inGramma = getGramma content
    doJob (head args) inGramma
    return ()

else do putStrLn "Invalid count of arguments!"
```

The problem is, when it reads from stdin, after every new line (enter pressed), it prints that line and than reads next. I need it to wait for the whole input and than print it out (after Ctrl+D).

Here are the functions used in that code:

```
-- | Structure of gramma
data GrammaStruct = Gramma
    { nonTerminals :: NonTerminals
    , terminals :: Terminals
    , start :: Start
    , rules :: Rules
    } deriving (Eq)

-- | Representation of gramma
instance Show GrammaStruct where
    show (Gramma n t s r) = 
                init (showSplit n) ++ 
        "\n" ++ init (showSplit t) ++ 
        "\n" ++ showStart s ++ 
        "\n" ++ init (showRules r)

-- | Print gramma
showGramma :: GrammaStruct -> IO ()
showGramma gr = do
    putStrLn $ show gr

-- | Transforms string given from file of stdin into gramma representation in app
getGramma :: String -> GrammaStruct
getGramma hIn = procLns (lines hIn)

-- | Depending on option given, provides required functionality
doJob :: String -> GrammaStruct -> IO ()
doJob op gramma
        | op == "-i" = showGramma gramma
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not that the question is _wrong_, per se, but "wait for the whole input and then print it out" is a pretty anti-modular requirement. I wouldn't be surprised if that requirement disappears or even becomes a problem for you later in the development of this tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `getContents` uses lazy IO, making the input stream to be processed line-by-line.  If you want to force it to read the whole input before starting performing the job you can use the following hack:

```
...
if length args == 1 then do
    content <- getContents
    length content `seq` return ()   -- force the input to be fully read now
    let inGramma = getGramma content
    doJob (head args) inGramma
    return ()
```

Alternatively, use `evaluate`, or look in Hackage for a strict IO module providing a strict `getContents`. For instance, I just found the `strict-io` package providing [`System.IO.Strict.getContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-io-0.2.1/docs/System-IO-Strict.html#v:getContents). Using that you should be able to write (untested)

```
import qualified System.IO.Strict as S
...
if length args == 1 then do
    content <- run S.getContents
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not answering the question but instead of testing the length of the arguments, you can pattern match against it and return the *correct* content

```
main = do
    let (opt, contentM) = case getArgs of
              [opt]       -> (op, getContent)
              [opt, file] -> (op, hGetContent file)
              _           -> error ("Invalid count of argument")
    inGramma  <- fmap getGramma contentM
    doJob opt inGramma
```